# Magento - Notification of refund order

Tags: magento

In magento, how do we send the client a notification from the website that an order has been refunded? and can we update the status to show that it was refunded?

Magento version : 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Magento User Guide](http://www.magentocommerce.com/resources/user-guide-download).  See Step 6 below for e-mail notification.

**Refunding**

You can create a record of a product refund from an existing order by generating a 
credit memo.

To view the list of refunds made in your web store:

From the Sales menu, select the Credit Memos option to display the Credit Memos page.

To refund a product from an existing order:

Note: You can create credit memos only for orders for which invoices were created. Without an invoice, an order is assumed not to be paid so that there is nothing to refund.

1. In the Admin Panel, select Sales > Orders to display a list of the existing orders.
2. Click the View link on the right side of the row of the desired order to display the 
   order view page.
3. Click the Credit Memo button to generate a credit memo.
4. Scroll down to the Items to Refund area, and in the Qty to Refund field of each
   relevant product, specify the quantity of products to refund.
5. To specify that this product was actually returned to the web store, select the Return 
   to Stock check box.

**6. (Optional) Select the Email Copy of Credit Memo check box to automatically send an email to the customer that the order has been refunded. You can also adjust the refund totals to match your business rules.**

**Managing Orders and Customers**

1. Click the Refund button at the bottom of the page. The total of the order from which 
   this product was refunded is updated automatically.
2. Click the Back button to return to the orders page where you can create additional 
   orders, if required.

Note: Refunding an order in Magento CE does not cause an actual payment refund. You must refund the payment on your own. The credit memo is only a record used to track the refunds and to provide proper values in the reports.

Comment: Dont see this option, only unsubscribe from newsletter and append comments `6. (Optional) Select the Email Copy of Credit Memo check box to automatically send an email to the customer that the order has been refunded. You can also adjust the refund totals to match your business rules.`

Comment: This is most likely an outdated answer. I answered this question 6 years ago.